# Can't cast generic sets?

Tags: java, generics

I'm ran into an interesting issue today. Consider the following code

```
public static class Parent {}
public static class Child extends Parent {}

Set<Child> childs = new HashSet();
Set<Parent> parents = (Set<Parent>)childs; //Error: inconvertible types

Parent parent = (Parent)new Child(); //works?!
```

Why wouldn't a cast like that work? I would expect that an implicit cast wouldn't work due to the various rules of generics, but why can't an explicit cast work?

Comment: If you say `HashSet<Child>` it might be.

Comment: @ahmet say `HashSet<Child>` _where?_

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The cast doesn't work because [Java generics are not covariant](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html).

If the compiler allowed this:

```
List<Child> children = new ArrayList();
List<Parent> parents = (List<Parent>)children;
```

then what would happen in this case?

```
parents.add(new Parent());
Child c = children.get(0);
```

The last line would attempt to assign `Parent` to a `Child` — but a `Parent` **is not a `Child`!**

All `Child` are `Parent` (since `Child extends Parent`) but all `Parent` are not `Child`.

Comment: That is an interesting point. This is causing havoc though for my API though. Thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem. If it's that bad and you don't understand the right way to parameterize the API, ask another question with some specific examples, and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

A `Set<Parent>` can contain any subclass of `Parent`. A `Set<Child>` can contain any subclass of `Child`. So a subclass of `Parent` that isn't a subclass of `Child` would be allowed in one but not the other, making them incompatible types.

Answer (score 1):

Because a Set of Childs(sic) isn't a Set of Parents. Defining a generic (parameterized) Set is effectively the same thing as defining a new class so you're defining two disjoint classes.

Answer (score 1):

Though, the super type of generics work a bit differently :

```
Set<Child> childs = new HashSet();
Set<? extends Parent> parents = childs;
```

Set is the super type of set and Set

I recommend you read [this docs about generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) to understand that there is no inheritance between generic container just because it is not inheritance. Inheritance, before all, means specialization. Think of a box designed to hold animals, ok it could be derived by a box containing only tigers but then it would mean that box could do for tigers, of course, but also do all what the super type can do, including beeing a good box for all animals. There is something very messy for humans to think about both types of taxonomy : hyperonimic hierarchy (specialization, inheritance) and meronymic hierarchy (container/contained).

In your last line, no need to cast neither :

```
Parent parent = new Child();
```

Stéphane