# Struggling to come up with API with interfaces and generic sets

Tags: java, generics

I'm struggling to come up with an easy API [due to generics not being covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319163/cant-cast-generic-sets/6319313#6319313)

This is my new problem: I can't get a Set<> that does what I need. I've tried reading various guides but they all use lots of buzzwords that I get lost.

Consider the following classes

```
public class Parent {}
public class Child extends Parent {}
interface Store {
    public Set<Parent> getParents(); //PROBLEM!! This needs to change
}
```

At a minimum, I need these operations to work

```
Set<Parent> parents = store.getParents();
parents.add(new Parent()); 
parents.add(new Child()); 
store.getParents().add(new Child()); //Note the lack of generics

for(Parent curEntry : store.getParents()) {

}
```

Classes that implement Store need to be able to work with Child (meaning they have a Set that is child). They need to expose the Childs as Parents though to the outside world.

---

Attempt #1

```
interface Store {
    public Set<Parent> getParents();
}

class ConcreteStore implements Store {
    Set<Child> childs;
    public Set<Parent> getParents() {
        return (Set<? extends Parent>)childs; //ERROR: inconvertible types
    }
}
```

Attempt #2

```
interface Store {
    public Set<? extends Parent> getParents();
}

class ConcreteStore implements Store {
    Set<Child> childs;
    public Set<Child> getParents() {
        return childs;
    }
}

Store store = new ConcreteStore();
Set<? extends Parent> parents = store.getParents();
parents.add(new Child()); //ERROR: cannot find symbol
parents.add(new Parent()); //ERROR: cannot find symbol. What?!

for (Parent curEntry : store.getParents()) {
}
```

That version, while I really like it, means that adding and removing from the Set outside of the Concrete class isn't possible. Which makes it useless. What really puzzles me is that not even adding a Parent will work.

Attempt #3

```
interface Store<T extends Parent> {
    public Set<T> getParents();
}

public static class ConcreteStore implements Store<Child> {
    Set<Child> childs;

    @Override
    public Set<Child> getParents() {
        return childs;
    }
}

Store store = new ConcreteStore();
Set<Parent> parents = store.getParents();
parents.add(new Parent());
parents.add(new Child());

for (Parent curEntry : store.getParents()) { //ERROR: incompatible types. Found object, requited Parent
}
```

Note that here I know I can do `Store<Child> store = new DatabaseStore()`, but due to a layer of abstraction that isn't possible and would get lost. Besides, passing around generics everywhere that you use a Parent looks ugly.

--

I'm out of ideas on what to do. Doing this is way more complex than i thought. I really need some way to get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is unsolvable in the form you pose it.

- A `Set<Parent>` is a collection where you can add any `Parent` object, and all objects you get out of it are `Parent` objects.
- A `Set<Child>` is a collection where you can add any `Child` object, and all objects you get out of it are `Child` objects.

As we can see, there can't be an object which implements both these interfaces: If you can add any `Parent`, you can't be sure to get only `Child` objects out of it.  This means that your ConcreteStore can't say "I have only childs", but someone else is allowed to put parents in it.

The Java generics system is just made to avoid these errors - wherever the compiler barks, you are most probably doing something wrong.

- A `Set<? extends Parent>` is a collection of some unknown subtype of `Parent`. This means that we can't put anything in it (as we don't know the right type), and all we can get out of it are `Parent` objects.
- A `Set<? super Child>` is a collection of some unknown supertype of `Child`. This means that we can put a `Child` into it, but we can't be sure what we get out of it (apart from `Object`, which is the supertype of everything).

Back to your problem:

For your operations

```
Set<Parent> parents = store.getParents();
parents.add(new Parent()); 
parents.add(new Child()); 
store.getParents().add(new Child()); //Note the lack of generics

for(Parent curEntry : store.getParents()) {

}
```

to work, you don't need anything more than what you already posted:

```
public class Parent {}
public class Child extends Parent {}
interface Store {
    public Set<Parent> getParents();
}
```

But now there **can't be store implementations which have only Childs** - since you need to be able to add Parents.

You could make `Store` a parameterized type instead:

```
interface Store<X extends Parent> {
   public Set<X> getParents();
}
```

Then you would have

```
class ConcreteStore implements Store<Child> {
    Set<Child> childs;
    public Set<Child> getParents() {
        return childs;
    }
}
```

Of course, this still will not allow you to put parents in it, but now the callers can see this - and there could be another implementation which implements `Store<Parent>`, which would allow this.

Comment: Note that your example prevents a for loop from executing correctly (for some reason its giving an Object instead of a parent). You've given the first clear explanation though, which means that I just have to hide add() behind a method (addParent() in this example).

Comment: @TheLQ: Which example? Are you using the `Store<X>` as `Store` instead? Don't.

Comment: @TheLQ: And you can't add a parent object to a child set, however you are trying to mask it by other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a logical mistake here. Parent IS always someone's Child but Child IS NOT always someone's parent. Therefore, it does not make sense to extend Child from Parent. That, probably, triggers requirements for other methods that are hard to represent due to this logic reversal.

I suggest you introduce common superclass, for example, `Human` and then revisit your design. I bet things will get simpler.

Comment: I'm confused with your explanation. How is Child not always someones Parent when Child extends Parent?

Comment: Yes in your design it is. But I assume that design, at least, minimally represents relationships between real objects. And for real objects child is not always a parent.

Comment: @TheLQ: Alex means that the names `Child` and `Parent` are not optimally selected to represent your problem.

Comment: @Paŭlo Short explanation: There are 3 interfaces that all have sets of each other in some way. There are then 3 concrete classes that all implement the interfaces but need sets of the other concrete classes, not the interfaces. Elsewhere in the project only the interfaces are used with factory methods that create the necessary concrete objects. Problem is that the concrete classes can't return their own Set, which is bad. Only option I can come up with is to copy.

Comment: @Paulo Correct,Paulo. I also suggest that this reversal makes it harder to do correct design as our brains are wired in a certain way and will try to make some assumptions for us during design process.

Comment: @TheLQ so can you introduce super interface for all of them? And in this interface have a method to return a set to this interface?

Answer (score 0):

in Attempt #2 you can't add anything to that collection. That's way you get `cannot find symbol` on add method. 
As a fast answer: you can always use Parent[] (array) and returns will be covariant.

Comment: That's what really puzzled me about it.

Comment: If you read the book for SCJP it's explained why arrays can be used as you want, and Collections not.

Comment: nice question, I'm interested in the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment but my rep is too low yet ...

What is the point of creating a concrete class which can only hold Child ?

I would keep :

```
class ConcreteStore implements Store {
    Set<Parent> parents;
    public Set<Parent> getParents() {
        return parents;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because in reality the Concrete classes need to refrence each other in my project, not the interfaces.